# VBA Conditional Formatting with Dynamic Expression Reference, Error 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA macro which will apply conditional formatting to a repetitive range of cells. Something is wrong with the expression though, and I cannot figure out how to get it to work. No matter what, I get runtime error 5, Invalid Procedure call or argument. When I set the expression to something not dynamic (a static reference) it works.

My code looks like this

```
Sub Cond_Format()

Dim row1, row2, row3, row4 As Integer
Dim rng1, rng2, rng3 As Range
Dim target1, target2, target3 As Range
Dim form1, form2, form3 As String

For i = 0 To 9

row1 = 3 + (4 * i)
row2 = row1 + 1
row3 = row2 + 1
row4 = row3 + 1

Set rng1 = Range("E" & row2 & ":Q" & row2)
Set rng2 = Range("E" & row3 & ":Q" & row3)
Set rng3 = Range("E" & row4 & ":Q" & row4)

Set target1 = Range("Q" & row1)
Set target2 = Range("Q" & row1 & ":Q" & row2)
Set target3 = Range("Q" & row1 & ":Q" & row3)

form1 = "=" & target1.Address & ">=60"""
'form2 = "=""sum(" & target2 & ")>=60"""
'form3 = "=""sum(" & target3 & ")>=60"""

'MsgBox (target3)

rng1.Select
With Selection
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=form1 '<-- Error Line
.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
End With
 With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

When I tried a macro recording, it produced a formula which works. Editing the formula to be dynamic is breaking it.

```
'Line from Test Macro Recording
Range("E4:Q4").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=""Q3>=60"""
```

I'm teaching myself VBA code, and this one is stumping me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be `Formula1:="=Q3>=60"`  The Address method has additional optional parameters which determine which part(s) of the reference are absolute. FYI if all cells in E:Q should be formatted according to the value in Q, you'd need `Formula1:="=$Q3>=60" (ie. absolute column reference) otherwise F will look at R, G will look at S, etc.

Comment: Also FYI - *every variable* in a Dim needs a type, unless you want a Variant.  So `rng1` and `rng2` will be `Variant`, not `Range`

Comment: `form1 = "=" & target1.Address & ">=60"`

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks for the input Tim, you led me towards the solution.

Used the messagebox to debug some of my variables, **Target1 had to be a string**, not a range. And I had extra quotation marks at the end of my formula. Formatting as the following did the trick.

```
form1 = "=" & target1 & ">=60"
```